# Advantages of multiple static blocks

Tags: java, static-block

```
class A{
    static{
      //initialize all things here
    }
}
```

This is the way I use static blocks in my code. But as we can also keep *multiple static* blocks in a class

```
class A{
   static{
      //do something here
   }

   static{
      //do something else here
   }
}
```

I have seen cases where multiple static blocks have been used, but can't seem to figure out why?

I suppose if it is for readability below method can also be used

```
class A{
    static{
       someMethod();
       someOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Are there any other advantages of multiple static blocks other than readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case second one is more readable,as you said.  [static blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) are executed by the order they placed.In  your case there is no other benefits /performance issues.

Comment: I'd rather invest some time in avoiding these blocks at all. How do you test this code?

Comment: @pimpf0r he might not using,he saw some where and asking for curiosity hopefully :)

Comment: I use static blocks for List/Map initialization.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, so you use static Maps in classes, available to all instances of subclasses? You sure when exactly these maps are initialized? Which instance is the first? you synchronize these maps, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not so serious answer: You may use multiple static blocks spread all over the class (at the beginning, the very end) to obfuscate initialization and access to fields and methods. Through this you really well cemented that noone else will touch your class, because slightest changes in those static blocks will completely change the behaviour of your class. ;-)

Somewhat serious: If you have to use these static blocks (of which I am really *NOT* a fan of, as you might have realized by now), I recommend to put them on the top of the class, well documented and all in one, as you suggested. Depending on the length you might consider static methods. But keep them together, recognizable for the next (poor) soul to work with it.